# export caf to itunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, m4a

I have a program that creates a caf file and I want to be able to export it. My program lets you export using UIActivityViewController, but if you pass it an m4a or wav file, it just lets you email the file. I would like to add the sound to the user's iPod music. Am I missing something easy? I know apple has other hooks, but want to do like the same as the voice memo works.

Thanks

Luke